# Find if Index is null in a ArrayList binary tree

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-tree

This is a uni project, where we code a "tree of life" that makes questions and it goes filling itself with the user's answers, as a binary tree it has "holes" in it, so basically it can have some data on index 20 but not on 15, so .size() wouldn't work either

This is giving me issues, since I need to know if a certain index is null, but ArrayList.get returns IndexOutOfBoundsException (as documented) if nothing is found

```
if(tree.get(next) == null){ 
                String nName = getInput();
                String nCarac = getInput(nName,nome);
                tree.add(next,nCarac);
                tree.add(next+Math.pow(2,height), nName);
                restart();
            }else{
                question(next,height);
            }
```

What would be the way to solve this issue?

It is not a "regular" binary tree, this is how it looks :

```
              o
             / \
            o   o
            |   |
            o   o
           / \ / \
          o   oo  o
```

Comment: *"but ArrayList.get returns an error if nothing is found"* .. a secret error so you can't tell us about that? If not, then please post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: @Tom edited with answer, the error is expected

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` means you're not checking a "hole", you're trying to access an index which is out of the arraylist bounds. Something like `index < 0` or `index >= size()`.

Comment: If you need holes, you're better off using a static raw array, instead of an arraylist.

Comment: Since when does `ArrayList.get` throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if an element is `null`? That exception is only thrown when you you access an element that is out of bounds.

Comment: @ControlAltDel what if I need "holes" and undefined zide?

Comment: @Mojimi Ashraful Islam provided one solution, one I would reocmmend. The other I can think of is to create your own dynamically expanding array

Comment: @AshrafulIslam if a HashMap contains "holes" how can I effectively iterate through it? I need to de-serialize it at one point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that you're trying to add a value at a place in the array that doesn't exist yet. It's not possible to add a value after an index that is out of bounds -

```
tree.add(next+Math.pow(2,height), nName);
```

is probably out of bounds.

I think that you should consider another data structure. Like you said: a tree. Instead of making tree an ArrayList<>, you should probably have a

```
class TreeNode{
ArrayList children = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
...Some other properties like "nName" and nome ...
}
```

Creating the tree you can have a root node and add children consecutively - eg:

```
TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
TreeNode childLevel1 = new TreeNode();
root.children.add(childLevel1);
TreeNode childLevel2 = new TreeNode();
childLevel1.children.add(childLevel2);
```

which gives a tree two levels deep with one node at each level.

```
root
  |
childLevel1
  |
childLevel2
```

- But maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?